# Using Collectors with joining char delimiter

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, collectors

I'm building a query param called "id", it's a list so I have something like localhost:8080/application?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4

(I know my method isn't enough and I need write the first *?id=*)

Method

```
public Map<Long, String> getSkus(List<ItemPedido> itensPedido) {
    Map<Long, String> skus = new HashMap<>();
    String ids = itensPedido.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getProduto() != null)
            .map(i -> i.getProduto().getId())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("&id="));
    //TODO 
    return skus;
}
```

My question is: Why I received this error in *Collectors.joining("&id=")*?

```
no suitable method found for collect(java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.CharSequence,capture#1 of ?,java.lang.String>)
[ERROR]     method java.util.stream.Stream.<R>collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super java.lang.Long>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) R
[ERROR]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[ERROR]     method java.util.stream.Stream.<R,A>collect(java.util.stream.Collector<? super java.lang.Long,A,R>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,A
[ERROR]         (argument mismatch; java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.CharSequence,capture#1 of ?,java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Collector<? super java.lang.Long,A,R>))
```

I'm using OpenJDK

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What type is `getId()` from `getProduto()` (from `ItemPedido`)? I'm going to **guess** *not* a `String`.

Comment: try `.map(i -> i.getProduto().getId().ToString())` assuming `getId()` returns a `Long`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thats it! Thanks

Comment: Consider `.map("id="::concat).collect(Collectors.joining("&", "?", ""))`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch technically speaking, any type of `CharSequence` would suffice not just `String`.

Comment: @Aominè Fair enough. It's probably not a `CharSequence` ***either***.

Answer (score 1):

Map your stream to a stream of Strings:

```
.map(i -> i.getProduto().getId().toString())
```